# apply a patch to fix a bug in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

Hi I try to fix a bug in cassandra

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4432

see the last comment

> Integrated in Cassandra #1673 (See
>   https://builds.apache.org/job/Cassandra/1673/) change
>   System.currentTimeMillis() to FBUtilities.timestampMicros(), related
>   to CASSANDRA-4432 (Revision 346ac03c29cd1fe763bd01077a5e0c59f12181b3)
>   Result = ABORTED xedin :  Files :
>   src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/MigrationManager.java

how do I fix it?

apply the patch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the source code of your version of Cassandra then apply the patch by the command `git apply`.

Something like that should work:

```
git clone http://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cassandra.git --branch cassandra-1.1.1 cassandra
cd cassandra
wget https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12535872/CASSANDRA-4432.patch
git apply CASSANDRA-4432.patch
```